What is the essential difference between ListenableBuilder and InheritedNotifier widgets in flutter?
Could please someone to explain what is the essential difference between ListenableBuilder and InheritedNotifier widgets?

ListenableBuilder:
Think of it as a helper that rebuilds a specific part of your UI whenever something it listens to (like a ValueNotifier or ChangeNotifier) changes, so use it when just one small part of your UI depends on changes in a Listenable.
InheritedNotifier:
This is more advanced and is used to share a Listenable with many widgets in your app. It helps efficiently notify only those widgets that care about the changes, avoiding unnecessary rebuilding, so use it when you need to share and manage changes across a group of widgets in the tree.

For more details you can refer official document also

